# XSLT changing the node based on it containing and xref of a certain type

Tags: xml, xslt

So I have the following xml in my file:

```
<p><xref type="special" href="X1FZIEHJOT">special</xref></p>
```

When I have an xref with type="special" I want to change the `<p></p>` to the following:

```
<div class="special"> ... </div>
```

This seems like it should be pretty simple, but I can't get it to work.
I am also changing the xref at the same time to the following:

```
<div class="special X1FZIEHJOT special=true color=#cccccc">&nbsp;</div>
```

Using the following xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="xref[@type='special']">
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
   <![CDATA[<div class="special ]]></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@href"/> 
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
   <![CDATA[ special=true color=#cccccc">&nbsp;</div>]]>    
   </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The verbal description of the first two examples sounds as if you want to write a template `<xsl:template match="p[xref[@type = 'special']]"><div class="special"> ... </div></xsl:template>`. I don't understand the rest unless you want  `<xsl:template match="p[xref[@type = 'special']]"><div class="special {xref/@href}"> ... </div></xsl:template>`. Not sure what the `special=true color=#cccccc` is supposed to do in a `class` of a `div`. What is the target document format, HTML?

Comment: Yes HTML for an in house browser.